# Find Components of Electric Field Perpendicular to Magnetic Field (without Maxwell's Eq)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, vectors, vector-fields

Given that the path of a 'charged particle' is a spiral inscribed in a paraboloid with the parameterized vector function below, I want to use only the Lorentz Force equation to solve for the magnetic field in the z direction.

$$\vec{r} = (at\cos(at),at\sin(at),Rt^{2})$$

Here are the assumptions I can make based on the system to help reach a solution:

1.The E and B fields are parallel and point only in the z direction

2.The acceleration is 2R (a constant), so the E field supplying this acceleration is also constant.

3.The magnetic field is a function of time, B(t)

4.The x,y,z components of velocity and acceleration can be computed from the position function given above.

So using the Lorentz Force equation (where the mass-charge ratio is set to one)
$$\vec{a} = \vec{E} +\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$$

$$\vec{a}=v_{y}B_{z}\hat{x}+v_{x}B_{z}\hat{y}+E_{0}\hat{z}$$

How can I solve for Bz in this equation?

**NOTE**: This is not a model of an actual charged particle in motion but is instead an analogy for specific crack propagation, so please do not refer to Maxwell's Equations. I also don't think energy is conserved in this case, but if you believe otherwise, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 equations for each component, so in general you'll need 3 variables. So in this particular case there is no way you can fulfil the equations by having only $E_z$ and $B_z(t)$.

Here are all the possible cases with $B_z\ne0$, constant $E_z$ and 3 zero components.

*case 1* ($E_x=0$, $B_x=0$, $B_y=0$)
\begin{equation}
B_z(t)= -a\frac{2 \sin{at}+a t \cos{at}}{\sin{at}+a t \cos{at}},~~~
E_y(t)= \frac{a^3 t}{\sin{at}+a t \cos{at}}~~~
E_z= 2R
\end{equation}

*case 2* ($E_y=0$, $B_x=0$, $B_y=0$)
\begin{equation}
B_z(t)= a\frac{at \sin{at}-2 \cos{at}}{\cos{at}-a t \sin{at}},~~~
E_x(t)= \frac{a^3 t}{\cos{at}-a t \sin{at}},~~~
E_z= 2R
\end{equation}

*case 3* ($E_x=0$, $E_y=0$, $B_y=0$)
\begin{equation}
B_x(t)= \frac{a^3}{2 R \sin{a t}+2 a R t \cos{a t}},~~~
B_z(t)=-a\frac{ 2 \sin{a t}+a t \cos{a t}}{\sin{a t}+a t \cos{a t}},~~~
E_z=\frac{a^4}{2 R}+2 R
\end{equation}

*case 4* ($E_x=0$, $E_y=0$, $B_x=0$)
\begin{equation}
B_y(t)= \frac{a^3}{2 R \cos{a t}-2 a R t \sin{a t}},~~~
B_z(t)=-a\frac{ at \sin{a t}-2 \cos{a t}}{\cos{a t}-a t \cos{a t}},~~~
E_z=\frac{a^4}{2 R}+2 R
\end{equation}

Though they still (likely) do not satisfy Maxwell's equations, so they're non-physical.

**UPD**

Doing maths for just one case. You differentiate (each component of) $\mathbf{r}(t)$ and get $\mathbf{v}(t)$ and then again - $\mathbf{a}(t)$. For *case 1* you have 3 equations for each component:
$$
x:~~a^3 (-t) \cos {a t}-2 a^2 \sin {a t}=0+a^2 B_z t \cos {a t}+a B_z \sin {a t}\\
y:~~2 a^2 \cos {a t}-a^3 t \sin {a t}=E_y+a^2 B_z t \sin {a t}-a B_z \cos {a t}\\
z:~~2R=E_z+0
$$

So we get a system of 3 equations with 3 variables $Ez$, $E_y$, $B_z$, which can be solved.